# android wifiManager :get information

Tags: android, wifi

I'm tryning to get the wifi informations .I can get those infromation in the logcat ,but i would like to put these information in an array (I would like to display them )
this is the code :

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        String SSID ;

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {




if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)){
                List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
                String resultsString ; 
                resultsString = results.toString() ;
                Log.i("resultsString",resultsString);
                List<WifiConfiguration> resultsConf =      wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();}
```

and this is a part from logcat :

```
03-26 09:23:58.273: I/wifi(518): bssid=xxxxxxxxxx
03-26 09:23:58.273: I/wifi(518): freq=2462
03-26 09:23:58.273: I/wifi(518): level=-44
03-26 09:23:58.273: I/wifi(518): tsf=0002403679437152
03-26 09:23:58.273: I/wifi(518): flags=[WPA-PSK-TKIP][ESS]
03-26 09:23:58.273: I/wifi(518): ssid=ZIGBEE
03-26 09:23:58.273: I/wifi(518): ====
03-26 09:23:58.273: I/wifi(518): bssid=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
03-26 09:23:58.273: I/wifi(518): freq=2462
03-26 09:23:58.273: I/wifi(518): level=-63
03-26 09:23:58.275: I/wifi(518): tsf=0000092560692966
03-26 09:23:58.276: I/wifi(518): flags=[WPA-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPA2-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][ESS]
03-26 09:23:58.276: I/wifi(518): ssid=Livebox_M
03-26 09:23:58.276: I/wifi(518): ====
```

And like you see ,I didn't wrote any log in my code ,I tried to get from the "result" list but its display nothing. Thank you!